# Rotating a UIView around a bouncing ball on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I'm having a problem with rotating a view around a bouncing ball.

So far I have 2 UIViews within a ViewController. One of the views contains a CALayer with a quartz drawing of a ball on it. The other view contains a bezierpath of a square frame. The ball bounces around inside the frame. This all works fine.

The problem is that I have implemented a system that allows the user to rotate the frame using a pan gesture. This actually works pretty well too, except that when the frame is rotating the path of the ball starts to curve, when it should be heading in a straight line. All the collision detection still works, just the path of the ball that gets affected. Once rotation has stopped, everything works normally. I can't figure out why.

I'm using this piece of code to rotate the frame:

```
CGFloat translation = 250;
NSArray *temp = [[outer layer] sublayers];
CAShapeLayer *layer = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:layer.path];
[newPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-translation, -translation)];
[newPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotationCounter))];
[newPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation, translation)];
layer.path = newPath.CGPath;
```

Probably not the smartest way of doing it, but to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing!

I have tried to rotate the UIView using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    frame.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotationCounter));
     }];
```

But i got the same probem. I also tried using `CATransform3D` on the CALayer that the frame is drawn on, but again the same thing happened.

Also, the ball is being animated by a step timer, set at 60 fps.

Sorry if thats really vague and thanks to anyone who can help.

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put everything (frame path, and ball) inside a parent view, and then apply a rotation transform to that view. That will rotate the coordinate system of all the child views together, and everything should just rotate the way you want it to. Much simpler than what you're trying to do.

Comment: The rotation of the frame shouldn't affect the path of the ball at all. If I rotate the parent view then both frame and ball will be affected. I have previously changed the code for this so that both are CAShaplayers held within one UIView's Layer. I just use a CATransform on the shapelayer that's the frame. One thing is that if I set the frame to be a clear colour then rotating it causes no problems for the ball. I even spent a week learning and rewriting all the graphics in opengl, and the same thing happened!